# Does this system of matrix equations have an analytical solution?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations, symmetric-matrices, positive-definite

The following matrices are all $n\times n$ and real.

$\beta$, $\Sigma_{11}$, $\Sigma_{21}$ and $\Sigma_{22}$ are all known.  Moreover, $\left(\begin{array}{cc}
     \Sigma_{11} & \Sigma_{21}' \\
   \Sigma_{21} & \Sigma_{22}
\end{array}\right)$ is positive definite.

$A$, $H$, $D_u$, and $D_v$ are unknown.  Moreover, $D_u$ and $D_v$ are diagonal.

These matrices satisfy the following:

$\Sigma_{11} = AD_vA' + \beta AD_uA'\beta'$

$\Sigma_{21} = HD_vA' +  AD_uA'\beta'$

$\Sigma_{22} = HD_vH' +  AD_uA'$

$D_v + D_u = I$

The unknown matrices have $2n^2 +2n$ independent entries. Because of the symmetric and diagonal structures, the matrix equations are really $\frac{n(n+1)}{2} + n^2 +\frac{n(n+1)}{2} + n = 2n^2 +2n$ scalar equations.  So I suspect that this has a solution, unique up to signs/reordering.  I can solve the scalar case where $n=1$, but am stumped when $n>1$.  Any ideas?  If necessary, we can assume $\beta$ or $\Sigma_{21}$ are invertible, but I would prefer not to.

Thanks!

Comment: I'd eliminate one of the D's in terms of I-D (the other D), for starters

Comment: Yeah, that step is certainly doable.  I figured the system was easier to read without the elimination.  But here's what it would look like:

$\Sigma_{11} = AD_vA' - \beta AD_vA'\beta' + \beta AA'\beta'$

$\Sigma_{21} = HD_vA' -  AD_vA'\beta' +  AA'\beta'$

$\Sigma_{22} = HD_vH' - AD_vA' + AA'$